# Travis CI & Symfony2 integration .travis.yml issue

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, travis-ci

I am trying to sync my Symfony2 project with Travis CI. I followed all the instructions and managed to set everything up correctly. My final hurdle is .travis.yml file which i have added under the root directory of Symfony project.

Content of my .travis.yml file:

```
php:
 - 5.4

script:
 - ./binphpunit -c app

notifications:
 email:
 - myemail@gmail.com
```

My phpunit is installed under `bin/phpunit` as binary

Error log:

```
/usr/bin/env: php No such file or directory
The command "./bin/phpunit -c app" exited with 127
```

Comment: Also, you can use Travis's phpunit just by calling `phpunit`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you miss the language specification. Try putting this:

```
language: php
```

as first line. 
Double check the phpunit travis configuration, probably simply without any path.

Check an example [here](https://github.com/mbiagetti/acme-social-backend/blob/master/.travis.yml)

Hope this help